# CSS: media queries on pc and phone

Tags: html, css, media-queries

While studying Emacs, I'm creating a web page ([Prince](https://arahasmas.gitlab.io/prince/)). The number of columns is managed by the following directives:

```css
body {
    font-family: var(--s-font-family);
    font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    body {
        column-count: 3;
        column-gap: 10px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 799px) {
    body {
        column-count: 2;
        column-gap: 8px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    body {
        column-count: 1;
        column-gap: 0;
    }
}
```

as you can see in the [CSS stylesheet](https://gitlab.com/arahasmas/prince/blob/master/public/style.css).

Now if I test the above code on my desktop pc (with Firefox 70), modifying the width of the browser window, everything work as expected. But when I open the page with my smartphone (whose size is 774x412 px, as reported by [webfx](https://www.webfx.com/tools/whats-my-browser-size/)) I see ever three columns, as if the media queries would be totally ignored by the browser.

Where can it be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just have to add the following meta tags in the head tag of your html page

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

to the head of your page